# insert into using same row(same primary key) mysql php pdo

Tags: php, mysql

```
INSERT INTO courses1 (sys_id,name, location) 
SELECT *
FROM courses 
WHERE sys_id= $sysid
```

I have the two tables above and I want to insert in course1 what I have in course. But I get problem with `sys_id` because I get `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'' in` so what I did is a added a column in courses1 named `system_id` but then I get another error saying column not match.

`Tried`

`INSERT IGNORE INTO` but ther result is not what I am expecting. The result I want is to have the data from course to course1 everytime I make a transaction. I want the data not to be overriden.

1. What is the best solution for `insert into` when inserting same row(same primary key)?

`UPDATE`

My aim is to back-up the data (historical data). I want to record the data before editing it. basically what i am doing is inserting the data in another table before updating it

Comment: Why do you need two tables?

Comment: for back up purposes. historical data. i want to record the data before editing it. basically what i am doing is inserting the data in another table before updating it. @YourCommonSense

Comment: You have inserted 3 columns (sys_id, name, location) and you passed the values of 4 column as sys_Id is autoincrement.

Comment: @HarshSanghani updated. both tables are the same in column names. to clarify with you comment above

Comment: now you have updated complete wrong query.

Comment: What you want is working completely different way. If you want a history table, it have to have completely different structure from the main table. At least it should have a non-unique key for the id from the main table.

Comment: @YourCommonSense as i understand from `insert into select` both tables needs to have same column names. if i have different column structure will it ok?for example in course1 the sys_id will be just normal column?not primary key and auto increment? is this what you are trying to say?

Comment: i think you have to make sys_id auto increment primary key in your backup table courses1 and create an index named coursesid to add in courses1 table for reference to courses table

Comment: you keep historical data from one table to another, check the updated answer this one covers what you try to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a perfect example that demonstrates the fact that **to give an answer, one have to understand the context of the question,** not just write an automated post triggered by some keyword in the question.

If you want a history table, it have to have a different structure from the main table. At least it should have a non-unique key for the id from the main table.

So, make a history table of the same structure, but add a `main_id` field. That gives you a structure like

```
id
manin_id
name
location
```

Then, to add a record into a history table,

```
INSERT INTO courses_history SELECT NULL, * FROM courses  WHERE sys_id=?
```

you may want also to add an index (non-unique) for the `main_id` field.

This way it will allow to store multiple "replicas" of the same row from the main table.

To get the last replica, you need a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM courses_history WHERE sys_id=? ORDER BY id desc
```

Comment: `main_id` will be AI and set to primary key?

Comment: you cannot have AI for the main_id in a *history* table. the very point of your question is to make a history table allow multiple rows with the same sys_id. thus it cannot be a primary key.